# torch.Linear weight doesn't update

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

```
#import blah blah

#active funtion
Linear = torch.nn.Linear(6,1)
sig = torch.nn.Sigmoid()

#optimizer
optim = torch.optim.SGD(Linear.parameters() ,lr = 0.001)

#input
#x => (891,6)

#output
y = y.reshape(891,1)
 
#cost function
loss_f = torch.nn.BCELoss()



for iter in range (10):
  for i in range (1000):
    optim.zero_grad()
    forward = sig(Linear(x)) > 0.5
    forward = forward.to(torch.float32)
    forward.requires_grad = True 
    loss = loss_f(forward, y)
    
    loss.backward()
    optim.step()
```

in this code, I want to update Linear.weight and Linear.bias but It doesn't work,,
I think my code doesn't know what is weight and bias so, I tried to change

```
optim = torch.optim.SGD(Linear.parameters() ,lr = 0.001)
```

to

```
optim = torch.optim.SGD([Linear.weight, Linear.bias] ,lr = 0.001)
```

but It still didn't work,,

// I wanna explain more detail in my problem but my English level is so low  sorry

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The BCELoss is defined as

[image]

As you can see the input `x` are probabilities. However your use of  `sig(Linear(x)) > 0.5` is wrong. Moreover, `sig(Linear(x)) > 0.5` return a tensor with no autograd and it breaks the computation graph. You are explicitly setting the `requires_grad=True` however, since the graph is broken it cannot reach the linear layers during back propagation and so its weights are not learned/changed.

#### Correct sample usage:

```
import torch
import numpy as np

Linear = torch.nn.Linear(6,1)
sig = torch.nn.Sigmoid()

#optimizer
optim = torch.optim.SGD(Linear.parameters() ,lr = 0.001)

# Sample data
x = torch.rand(891,6)
y = torch.rand(891,1)

loss_f = torch.nn.BCELoss()

for iter in range (10):
    optim.zero_grad()
    output = sig(Linear(x))
    loss = loss_f(sig(Linear(x)), y)
    
    loss.backward()
    optim.step()

    print (Linear.bias.item())
```

Output:

```
0.10717090964317322
0.10703673213720322
0.10690263658761978
0.10676861554384232
0.10663467645645142
0.10650081932544708
0.10636703670024872
0.10623333603143692
0.10609971731901169
0.10596618056297302
```